# Mongoid - Different Collection for Same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm creating an application (Ruby on Rails+MongoDB+Mongoid) where collections are created by Model(Example: Measure). Now i need to create different collection of same Model(Measure) and each collection is differentiated based on certain value(`companyid`). Every query to the database will only need to access collection based on `companyid`. I feel it's a good idea to separate  collection for better performance.

I used to have a single Model because I used to have everything in a single collection but now I need multiple collection for single Model, one per `companyid`.

Is there any possibility to achieve this

The model in ruby on rails looks like:

```rb
class CellMeasure
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :companyid, type: String
  field :value, type: String
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the collection used for a particular operation at runtime via the runtime persistence context. See https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-persistence/#runtime-persistence-options.